# %matplotlib inline doesn't work on iPython and Jupyter console

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter

I'm trying out Jupyter console for the first time, but can't get the `%matplotlib inline` magic to work. Below is a screenshot of an example session:

[image: The window is a result of Line 6, and Line 7 didn't do anything at all.]
The plot shows in a separate window after I run Line 6, and Line 7 doesn't do anything.

When I run `%matplotlib --list`, `inline` is given as one of the options:

```
Available matplotlib backends: ['osx', 'qt4', 'qt5', 'gtk3', 'notebook', 'wx', 'qt',
'nbagg', 'agg', 'gtk', 'tk', 'ipympl', 'inline']
```

When I try to use another backend, say `qt5`, it gives an error message because I don't have any Qt installed.

```
ImportError: Matplotlib qt-based backends require an external PyQt4, PyQt5, or PySide
package to be installed, but it was not found.
```

Running `%matplotlib??` reads:

```
 If you are using the inline matplotlib backend in the IPython Notebook
        you can set which figure formats are enabled using the following::

            In [1]: from IPython.display import set_matplotlib_formats

            In [2]: set_matplotlib_formats('pdf', 'svg')

        The default for inline figures sets `bbox_inches` to 'tight'. This can
        cause discrepancies between the displayed image and the identical
        image created using `savefig`. This behavior can be disabled using the
        `%config` magic::

            In [3]: %config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'bbox_inches':None}
```

But I don't know if it's something I can tweak around to solve my issue.

When I try it the magic IPython console, it says `inline` is an `Unknown Backend`.

```
UnknownBackend: No event loop integration for u'inline'. Supported event loops are: qt, 
qt4, qt5, gtk, gtk2, gtk3, tk, wx, pyglet, glut, osx
```

I've also found [this issue on github](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/503) after some googling but I don't even know if it's relevant to my situation (most of their conversation didn't make sense to me lol).

Lastly, I'm not sure if this issue is related at all, but here it is, just in case: when I try to open Vim in Jupyter via the `!vim` command, it glitches pretty badly, preventing me from even exiting out of Jupyter itself without closing the terminal altogther. Vim works perfectly fine when called inside IPython console, however.

I'm using `matplotlib 2.0.0`.

If anyone could help me figure this out, that'd be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You’re running a console which is completely text based and incapable of showing images. Therefore, although `inline` is available, it's not producing inline output.

I'm not sure why it doesn't throw an error, though, which it does in my case:

[image]

You can use `%matplotlib inline` in a GUI console, like Jupyter QTConsole

[image]

or in a jupyter notebook in the browser

[image]

Comment: I actually got the same error when I first tried it, but somehow was able to get around it. I don't remember what exactly I did, though. Anyways thank you so much, it was so obvious but I don't know why I didn't realize that.. haha.

Answer (score 3):

`%matplotlib` without the `inline` works for me (I'm using osx and IPython 7.0.1)

Comment: update:
I'm using IPython 7.6.1 and %matplotlib doesn't seem to work for me anymore.

Comment: Like Brad said, you can't put inline images into a console... but I believe %matplotlib inline does have an effect on most systems - without it, you need plt.show() to display a graph in an external window, and it blocks input to the console until you close it. With %matplotlib inline you don't need plt.show() and it doesn't block the console.
It's also worth noting that you use %matplotlib osx on MacOS rather than inline.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running an old version of ipython try `%pylab inline` instead. See [notes in this tutorial](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jrjohansson/scientific-python-lectures/blob/master/Lecture-4-Matplotlib.ipynb)