# UnknownBackend: No event loop integration for u'inline' when enable inline matplotlib in emacs python notebook

Tags: python, emacs, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to enable the python notebook in emacs. I am following the instruction from this page: https://realpython.com/blog/python/emacs-the-best-python-editor/

When I tried to do "%matplotlib inline" so that I can show the plot inline, I got the following errors:

"UnknownBackend: No event loop integration for u'inline'. Supported event loops are: qt, qt4, qt5, gtk, gtk2, gtk3, tk, wx, pyglet, glut, OSX"

My emacs is 24.4 and jupyter notebook version is 4.3

Thanks

Comment: do you have matplotlib installed? what kernel in ein? it is really simple if you have anaconda and run anaconda mode

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem in my terminal... may be it could be this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616768/matplotlib-inline-doesnt-work-on-ipython-and-jupyter-console

Comment: @manandearth, yes, I installed the anaconda to include the matplotlib library. How can I check the kernel version ein? My matplotlib version is 2.0.2

Comment: @AnselmScholz, Thanks! I saw this post before but since I tried to use emacs as my single editor where I want to run the notebook, I am trying not to switch to another editor. Do you see that is possible still?

Comment: when you start a new notebook you can choose which kernel in the `ein:notebooklist-open` menu, a kernel in an open notebok can be altered or stopped or restarted ( very easily in the gui version just click on the kernel name, or go through the `M-x ein:...` commands. look also in [emacs ipython documentation](http://millejoh.github.io/emacs-ipython-notebook/index.html#quick-try)

Answer (score 3):

If you are running matplotlib on osx this helped resolve my problem:

1. I upgraded to matplotlib-2.2.0 [by now there is a new version 2.2.0](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301961/matplotlib-broken-after-pip-install-matplotlib-upgrade-to-version-2-1-0?rq=1)
2. Import matplotlib
3. calling `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` directly after the import of matplotlib.([comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784641/installation-issue-with-matplotlib-python)
4. importing pyplot
5. call pyplot.plot().
6. call `%matplotlib osx`

I had to call `%matplotlib osx` instead of `%matplotlib inline`[one of the comment mentiond it](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9834)

After that it worked.

Comment: Thanks Anselm. If I understand you correctly, your steps are:<br/>
1. upgrade matploblib-2.2.0<br/>
2. %matplotlib osx<br/>
3. import matplotlib<br/>
4. matploblib.use('TkAgg')<br/>
4. import matplotlib.pyplot as plt<br/>
5. plt.plot()<br/>

Is it correct?

Comment: Hi Minghui Liu, I edited my answer as it was not very clear... I hope it is better now.

Comment: Step 6 got it for me!