# Plotting inline in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using the terminal in jupyter and am trying to plot with matplotlib. I need to plot inline and so i use `%matplotlib inline` but i am getting the following error:

```
>>> %matplotlib inline
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    %matplotlib inline
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why am i getting this error? Is it because it is a terminal and not jupyter notebook type environment? I had tried the same code in jupyter notebook and it did not return any errors.

Comment: Yes, `%whatever` is an IPython magic command, which will only work in IPython (Jupyter uses IPython kernel by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `ipython` instead of `python` in the Jupyter terminal. Then you can execute any magic command.

Comment: I tried running ipython and got this error: `UnknownBackend: No event loop integration for 'inline'. Supported event loops are: qt, qt4, qt5, gtk, gtk2, gtk3, tk, wx, p
yglet, glut, osx`

Comment: Try to find solution in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49347477/unknownbackend-no-event-loop-integration-for-uinline-when-enable-inline-matpl
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616768/matplotlib-inline-doesnt-work-on-ipython-and-jupyter-console

Answer (score 0):

trying using `'exec(%matplotlib inline)'`. Works for me on python3.6